# How do you access control ESI routes in Symfony2 via a trusted proxy?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a series of routes that sit on `/esi/*` that need restricting from the public so that only the reverse proxy can see them.

I have the reverse proxy (localhost) set as a trusted proxy so that `$request->getClientIP()` returns the real IP of the user in subrequests.

How do I configure access control to block `/esi/*` from the public considering the IP never matches in the following configuration?:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/esi, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
    - { path: ^/esi, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6982

Looks to be an acknowledged issue, with a patch to allow use of the X-Forwarded-For header as the suggested workaround.